# Do I need to create the zones in /etc/bind/? {db.} Files

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind, domain-server

Use Webmin to create the master zones

```
> Direct Zone: fabyfashion.com
fabyfashion.com.      NS    dns.fabyfashion.com.
fabyfashion.com.      A     192.168.1.24
dns.fabyfashion.com.   A     192.168.1.24
www.fabyfashion.com.  CNAME fabyfashion.com.
ftp.fabyfashion.com.  CNAME www
```

```
> Zona inversa: 192.168.1
1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.          NS            dns.fabyfashion.com.
24.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.       PTR           fabyfashion.com.
24.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.       PTR           dns.fabyfashion.com.
```

But the files were not created in /`etc/bind/`

The DNS server says it works, but when looking for the domain in the network I get an error.

> NXDOMAIN

Files were created only in `/var/lib/bind` . Should I create them manually?

Video: [BIND9 Webmin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vL9pG8gLI84)

Comment: Please replace all images with text by a copy.paste of that text. I for one am not going to retype whatever is in those pictures to form an answer. Plus images can not be searched by others on askubuntu. We are here to help ALL of us not just you.

Comment: Heyy RINZWIND the files were not created in /etc/bind/

The DNS server says it works, but when looking for the domain in the network I get an error.

NXDOMAIN

Files were created only in /var/lib/bind . Should I create them manually?